# How to remove the white space below the caption text "Figure:" -- or: How to make figure caption completely justified (like a block)

Tags: floats, captions

I have picture and a caption. Below the string "Figure:" there is a lot of lost white space. I.e., the actual caption is left-aligned, but the "left line" starts after the colon of "Figure:" thereby losing a lot of space, see graphic:

[image]

So, I would like to eliminate this space -- how can that be done?

Here is the (minimal/standard) code producing the example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `\setcapindent{0pt}` to the preamble:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{scrartcl}% a4paper and twoside=false are defaults for scrartcl
\setcapindent{0pt}% <- added
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's actually described in the manual of the package `caption`: Simply use its option `plain` as follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[format=plain]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

... which will lead to the desired result:

[image]

Comment: I bet there is a way without any package. I don't have the class manual at hand, but the solution is in there.

Comment: 3.20 in scrguien.pdf